# Testing PHP CURL file uploads on laptop (blocked by Norton)

Tags: php, file-upload, curl

I'm testing PHP CURL on my laptop, but file uploads are blocked by Norton because of negative content length.

So, I think CURL is sending Content-Length: -1.

How do I get around that? By manually setting the content length? If so, what's the best way to do that?

Comment: I'll try this... length of query string + length of files. Then, use CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to set the content-length.

Comment: That seemed to work... but now the test hangs... I tried setting session_write_close() in case of a session deadlock, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: It looks like Norton is blocking all the CURL calls, whether or not I'm uploading a file.

Comment: Before I was using http_build_query to pass a string instead of array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, but that won't work for sending files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I had `curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE)`, and that wasn't a good idea. I removed it, and Norton doesn't complain and the script works.